# Play video files while they are still archived

Tags: windows, video, rar

I have a lot of **video files** that come **inside .rar archives**.

Normally I'd have to unpack them before I can watch the video, but [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) allows me to **play the archives** as if they have been unpacked.
I love this feature, but I'm not really keen on XBMC because I like to multitask while watching video, and it's just not meant to be used like that.

**Are there any other video players for Windows out there that have this amazing feature?**

If there's a Linux player that does this, I'd like to hear about that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Dziobas is supposed to work pretty well](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Multimedia/Video/Other-VIDEO-Tools/Dziobas-Rar-Player.shtml)